# How to Make WebView Work In iPhone/iPad Retina

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, retina-display

I am having a bit of trouble with my webview code. it is completely working with iPhone and iPad non-retina version but can't get it to work with retina.

I have provided my code below... What seems to be the problem here?

```
self.webView.delegate=self;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.google.com/";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView1 loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I'm an amateur programmer so please forgive me. I already did my google search but failed at finding the answer so here i am :)

edit: sorry guys for the incomplete info. it is not in xib or storyboard. also, the specific problem im having is when in retina, the webview opens and closes immediately, and then crashes the app. don't mind the crash as i understand why it happened. im just concerned about it not working on retina display even though it's completely fine with non-retina.

my original code is webView.delegate=self; and not self.webView.delegate=self;... i just changed it because i did some random testing. :/

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Is Web view in your .xib file or dynamically created? If it in your .xib file then you don't need to addsubview in your view.

Comment: Load different site rather than `google`.
it works for me.

Comment: thanks guys, i edited my original post and added the specific problem i'm having

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that your code is working in any device because there is a mistake in your `UIWebview` instance. it should be like this take a look at addsubview line what you're doing.

```
self.webView.delegate=self;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.google.com/";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Comment: yes thank you for pointing that out. my original code was webview only and not self.webview. i changed it because i experimented some stuff that didn't work. i now changed the addsubview to self.webview

Comment: @MattData : - have a look at your loadRequest line it's still webView1 there. replace that also with my code hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Comment: i don't think it's the problem because they're all without 'self' originally. i just added self when i was experimenting. thanks for the reply though